# Integración de Gentellela en Laravel

Tags: laravel, template

Buenas ¿Alguno de ustedes ha podido integrar Gentellela (Admin Template) Sobre Laravel 5.*? La documentación que hay es muy distintas en cada fuente. He probado todas y con ninguna me ha resultado...

Comment: ¿Qué luego gentellela no es solo html y javascript? Yo he usado Getellela con django y no necesité alguna configuración especial

Comment: Según la documentación (https://github.com/FlorientR/laravel-gentelella) realizo todos los paso, pero no me levanta el css.

Comment: ¿qué significa "levantar" el css?

Comment: pero en realidad lo que necesitas es [este](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/), puedes seguir trabajando igual que como trabajas con tu html de toda la vida, en el caso que uses algun motor de plantillas, es decir, no veo la necesidad de usar el laravel que trae getella cuando puedes añadirlo tu manualmente, a lo que me refiero es que gentellela es solo frontend, por lo que usualmente no depende de ningun lenguage de backend o servidor. debes servir los archivos de la misma forma que lo harias con otra app

Comment: Si vemos la [pagina oficial](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella), vemos que se la instalan mediante el bowser o npm, pero al yo hacer esto, no hace nada, me dice que se instaló y ya.

Comment: laravel maneja las rutas de forma diferente, debes asegurarte de que todos los css y los js estén en la carpeta public, y que los archivos html esten en assets/view con el formato .blade. Para obtener un recurso desde public, debes usar en tu plantilla blade algo como esto ```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/style.css') }}">```

Comment: Amigo, me gusta bastante como lo explica esta persona y ademas queda muy limpio
https://htr3n.github.io/2018/05/integration-laravel-gentelella/

Answer (score 3):

Si, entras a la carpeta public y ahí pones todos tus archivos css y js.
Luego te vas a la carpeta resource > view y ahí deberás crear un nuevo archivo ejemplo:

```
ejemplo.blade.php
```

Ahí puedes pegar el código HTML de la plantilla. Ya luego si deseas puedes crear una plantilla para que ahorres código, mas información:
[Plantillas Blade - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade)